# How can I create Multiple joins over 5 tables in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, relates

I have a relational database which uses the following relational schema to create a query:

Parcel.IsBooked is joined to Bookinglocation.ID

Bookinglocation.IsPartOf is joined to Bookingpage.id

Bookingpage.id is joined to Namenumber.isPartOf

Namenumber.called is joined to Person.id

This is the relationship path from the shapefile "parcel" to the table "Person" which contains the name of the parcel owner.

My question is....How is it possible with ArcGIS to select parcels from the shapefile and see the selection in the "Person" table? I seem to only be able to join a shp to a table...but not a table to a table. I need to actually remove names out of the "person" table which fulfill a certain criteria...so exporting tables joined to shapefiles won´t do the job. Is this possible with ArcGIS?

Comment: is this a one-time thing, or are you going to have to do this again in the future?

Comment: Will have to do it often...every month

Comment: I'm assuming you have a common field throughout all of the data tables and parcel shp?

Answer (score 3):

ideally, you'd want to move your data into the DBMS as a Feature Class and then create a relationship class in ArcMap.

Using SDE, you can load Shapefiles into MSSQL and setup relationships in ArcMap just like you have in SQL, then ArcMap would understand the Relationships.

Here's a good place to start: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Relationships_and_ArcGIS/004t00000001000000/

This page will outline relationship properties: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Relationship_class_properties/004t00000004000000/

Comment: So if I import my whole dataset into MSSQL I can create relationship classes to establish this relationship and select over 5 tables at once?

Comment: I don't know about the relating 5 tables, but you can create a View that combines the tables into one and do the relate to that one view.  The view will update as the table data updates.